# Websocket 'on_message' not executing

Tags: python, websocket

I'm connecting to a websocket using the websocket-client library for Python. Here is my code:

```
import websocket
import threading


class App():
    def __init__(self):
        self.value = 'Foo'


app = App()


def on_message(wsapp, message):
    app.value == 'Bar'
    print(app.value)

wsapp = websocket.WebSocketApp('wss://sample-url.com', on_message=on_message)
wsthread = threading.Thread(target=wsapp.run_forever)
wsthread.start()
(I'm making a thread because I want this to run in the background).‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎‎
```

However, it still prints 'Foo' instead of 'Bar'. Can someone help?

Comment: The `==` operator is the comparison for equality. In particular `app.value == 'Bar'` line does absolutely nothing. Did you want to use `=` instead?

Comment: Oops, yea I replaced == with = and it worked.